# Error “signature of public member contains native type” in Windows phone 8 RunTimeComponent

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winprt

I'm trying to create a runtime component which supports windows phone 8. 
Brief Description of the Program is as :

1. Application (C#) is going to fill some data in ref struct A
2. It will call init API of ref class VVoiP with object of ref struct A.
3. Ref class VVoip needs to have a array of objects of class B, so that it can have multiple instances.

C # Code :

```
using TestWRC;
namespace TestPrj
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            VVoIP v1 = new VVoIP();
            A a1 = new A();
            a1.a = 10;
            v1.init(a1);
        }
    }
}
```

C++ Code :

```
    namespace TestWRC
    {
    public ref struct A sealed
        {
    public:
        property int a;
    };

    struct B {
        A^ A_obj;
    };

    public ref class VVoIP sealed
    {
    private:
        B array[3];   /* Array of object to have multiple instance */

    public:
        void init(A a1);
    };
    }


using namespace TestWRC;
    void VVoIP::init(A a1)
    {
    array[0].A_obj->a = a1.a;  /* Filling local array with initialized data*/
    }
```

the following errors coming from the above code:

> error C3992: 'init':signature of public member contains invalid type 'TestWRC::A'

I am new to Windows phone 8, would somebody please say me what is this error, and how to rectify this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your public signature needs to specify that this is a Windows Runtime reference counted object, so you need to declare with the hat (^) syntax.

```
void init(A^ a1);
```